# Domain Name has hyphens and exact match, should I change it?

Tags: domains

The blog is currently a blogspot blog. Used part of the name of the real website that I got the idea to start a blog for.
Time to get a registered domain for it, instead of the( name.blogspot.com )it is now
I got itchy and bought a domain name that has 4 words and hyphens. Also, I believe it is an exact match domain.
I see now that hyphens are possibly bad and so maybe are exact match domains.
I am not sure if it is wise to use this new domain name or get a different one.
Or, if I use this domain name should i just get it with no hyphens, just a run on of 4 words.
A different alternative is to use the name of the site i originally started the blog for and add a couple words which I think would be exact matched domain. If I do that should I use hyphens or no hyphens.

Summary, Use hyphens or not in domain with 4 words but the 3 word is actually the letter n such as cookies-n-creme for example.
Or, use the real websites name plus the two word exact match meaning NAMEwordword.com If I go this route do i use hyphens or not.
I hope you can understand this question. Hard for me to put it into typing.
The reason it is exact match name is that it is actually descriptive of the blog and I haven't been able to come up with anything descriptive that isn't.

Comment: What is your domain name?

Comment: Sorry but there is many questions and answers already on the site regarding the usage of hyphens and several over about exact matching domains. To avoid disappointment in the near future please ensure that you search the site for existing duplicates and take a look at our [Help and Guidelines](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Well, maybe I didn't word it right. I see now a few different questions covered the whole topic. Just not in one question and answer. Thanks.    I actually just got what I hope now is a better one. Not so much of an exact match and only two words no hyphens and is still fitting.    Took so long to find an available one that was decent sounding!   Thanks